# Enable vertical scrolling on textarea

Tags: html, css

I have a textarea that I want to enable vertical scrolling. When I exceed the height of the textarea, it increases in size. The scroll bar does not appear. I want that a vertical scroll bar appears and the users are not able to resize the text area as well.

I searched online and tried solutions posted, but none seem to work.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hozefa/8fv6e/

CSS:

```
#imageURLId{
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: normal;
resize: none;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

HTML:

```
<label for="aboutDescription" id="aboutHeading">About</label>
<textarea rows="15" cols="50" id="aboutDescription"
    style="resize: none;"></textarea>
<a  id="imageURLId" target="_blank">Go to
    HomePage</a>
```

Comment: You are using jQuery mobile. Scrollbars are a bit annoying IMO on mobiles (specially touch-enabled).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can try adding:

```
#aboutDescription
{
    height: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;  
}
```

Comment: @MikeChristensen: Safari 5.1.2 (Mac OS)

Comment: @MikeChristensen: Changing it for #aboutDescription is working. I was making a stupid mistake.Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Hozefa - Glad to hear.  As for forcing it to use 15 lines but not allow resize, I'm not sure if you can do that.  Without a CSS fixed height, it seems to just resize as needed even with `resize:none;` - I suppose you'd have to convert your line height to pixels.

Comment: Ensure that you are not picking up the style white-space:nowrap on your textarea. You may want to explicitly set it to white-space:normal.

Answer (score 21):

Try this. It is another version of the answers.

```css
#imageURLId {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  resize: none;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<label for="aboutDescription" id="aboutHeading">About</label>
<textarea rows="15" cols="50" id="aboutDescription" style="max-height:100px;min-height:100px; resize: none"></textarea>
<a id="imageURLId" target="_blank">Go to
    HomePage</a>
```

Answer (score 8):

Simply, change

```
<textarea rows="15" cols="50" id="aboutDescription"
style="resize: none;"></textarea>
```

to

```
<textarea rows="15" cols="50" id="aboutDescription"
style="resize: none;" data-role="none"></textarea>
```

---

ie, add:

```
data-role="none"
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's your CSS

```
element{
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a fixed `height` and `overflow-y: scroll;`