# Wrapping and height increasing input React CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I try to make an input component where the text is wrapping and height of the input increases at each new line appear. I mean something like on desktop facebook. When you click on someone, open the message box and write something in the input, the input becomes larger every new text line.

I am using textarea for it:
`<Input />`

```
const Input = styled.textarea`
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  height: 24px;
`;
```

And after entering 5 lines of text, the scroll bar should appear. How can I do this?

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580991/enable-vertical-scrolling-on-textarea

Comment: not really, because the height doesn't increase every new line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it doesn't have to be a textarea, the [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) attribute can do this - add it to a `<div>` and set a max height for the scrollbar to appear:

```css
.demo {
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 20px;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo" contenteditable></div>
```

If it must be a textarea, then you will have to use a script to resize it - there's some good approaches listed here: [CSS Tricks: Auto growing inputs and textareas](https://css-tricks.com/auto-growing-inputs-textareas/#resizing-actual-input-elements)

**edit** Here's a demo in react, using the `contentEditable` attribute (use camelCase for React jsx) with a placeholder. The placeholder is added using a pseudo element:

```js
const ContentEditable = ({ placeholder }) => (
  <div class="demo" contentEditable="true" placeholder={placeholder}></div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <ContentEditable placeholder="Type something..." />, document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.demo {
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 20px;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

[contenteditable=true]:empty:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  color: #555;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The contenteditable method is fine, but how can I add this attribute to react component? I saw a lib for it ```react-contenteditable``` but this component doesn't has placeholder attribute.

Comment: sorry I should have included a react example - updated my answer with a react demo that has a placeholder