# How to wrap and move the content down vertically in react

Tags: reactjs

```
<div className={styles.searchContainer} contentEditable='true'>
  <div>John1</div>
  <div>John2</div>
  <div>John3</div>
  <div>John4</div>
  <input value={searchInput} onChange={e => this.handleTagInputChange(e.target.value)}
    onFocus={this.toggleContents}>
  </input>
</div>

.searchContainer {
  min-height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I have set `contentEditable` to true but content still doesn't wrap into next line. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: You want each John on a seperate line? What did you try?

Comment: Have you tried flex-wrap: wrap?

Comment: @0stone0 Yes on a new line. I have added contentEditable to true as per this example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69562816/wrapping-and-height-increasing-input-react-css

Comment: @Mossy82 flex-wrap: wrap will not help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the `display: flex;` that prevents the `contentEditable` to wrap.

You could add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to make it wrap

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {
    return (
        <div className="test" contentEditable='true'>
            {[...Array(50)].map((e, i) => <div>{"John" + (+i + 1)}</div>)}
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
.test {
    min-height: 30px;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: scroll;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
        
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I need to wrap into new line when there horizontally there is no space for items

Comment: Then i wouldn't recommend using contenteditoable at all