# I have a scrollable multiline React Native TextInput - Is it possible to show a scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

My Android React Native application has a simple React Native TextInput:

```
            <TextInput
                value={message}
                maxLength={2000}
                textAlignVertical="top"
                multiline={true}
                numberOfLines={4}
                onChangeText={onChange}
            />
```

It has a set height of 100px so if the text is long enough, it becomes scrollable, however, it does not show a scrollbar and I was wondering if adding a scrollbar is possible?

Comment: What you need is `overflow-y: scroll;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable vertical scrolling on textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580991/enable-vertical-scrolling-on-textarea)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to show a scrollbar in a scrollable multiline React Native TextInput. There are two ways to do this:

1. Set the `numberOfLines` property to a number greater than 1. This will allow the user to scroll through the text input if it exceeds the number of lines specified.
2. Wrap the `TextInput` in a `ScrollView` component. This will allow the user to scroll through the text input regardless of how many lines it contains.

Example:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { TextInput, ScrollView, View } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  return (
    <View>
      {/* Method 1 */}
      <TextInput
        multiline={true}
        numberOfLines={5}
        value={text}
        onChangeText={setText}
      />

      {/* Method 2 */}
      <ScrollView>
        <TextInput
          multiline={true}
          value={text}
          onChangeText={setText}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: @Onyx I think this answer should resolve your query.